# how to write a code for database connection from eclipse using spring. This should be a simple spring maven project without using spring boot

Tags: spring, oracle

I am new to spring. I am not able to figure out how to write a spring project for creating DB connection using maven , without using spring -boot or hibernate. it is supposed to be a simple spring maven project.

can you help me with few sample codes.

Comment: Search same thing on google you will find many examples. i.e https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data-access-with-jdbc/connect-oracle.html

Comment: Thanks! But how to i use spring data and curd operations without spring boot. Can you please provide some sample codes.

Comment: I have installed Spring tool suites. I am not able to get a sample code on google where spring data jpa (NOT using SPRING BOOT)is used to connect to oracle DB and repository of an entity extends CurdRepository. Can anyone please guide me with a working sample code

Answer (score 0):

Install the Spring tools suite plugin for eclipse from the following [link](https://download.springsource.com/release/STS4/4.2.1.RELEASE/dist/e4.11/spring-tool-suite-4-4.2.1.RELEASE-e4.11.0-win32.win32.x86_64.zip).

With spring tools suite, access the spring dashboard [image]

Select the Import Reference App, this will provide several example applications from the Spring guides, choose the example and the example will be installed onto your eclipse workspace. These examples are well documented , with clear instructions on how to run the project. Hopefully this should help you get started with learning Spring framework.